# Do not want display launch image after loading app first time

Tags: iphone, xcode

I do not want to display launch image after app loading first time.Sometimes my app getting struck with launch image for long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launch image is displayed till the time controll is in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

i guess you are doing some heavy lifting there try doing things in background this will display launch image for small duration.

if you want to display after second time app is launched set a respective bool in userdefaults

Answer (score 0):

Your app got struck due to heavy loading of data in your viewdidload method of you firstviewcontroller.To show your loading screen for less time add your stuff you done in viewdidload in another method and call it after few seconds like

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(loaddata) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

-(void)loaddata
{
   write you viewdidload stuff here
}
```

Comment: how do i not displaying launch image after loading app first time?

Comment: if you are using Default.png as your default image the it will display always, since this mechanism is controlled by ios and if you are showing your launch image programmtically(as imageview ) then you can control it ..

Comment: you can add imageview to your viewdidload  and after some time remmove it, also to check wether you app opens  first time use nsuserdefault